# Dynamically allocating structures with vectors in them

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector, new-operator, delete-operator

If I have a dynamically allocated struct with a vector in it, when does the vector go out of scope? Will the vector destructor be called when I delete the struct, or do I need to force the destructor call before deleting the struct?

Answer (score 2):

When you dynamically allocate the struct, you're also allocating everything inside it.  The struct and everything in it gets destroyed when the struct is deleted.  The compiler takes care to make sure all the destructors are called.

Answer (score 0):

The vector will stay alive until you delete your struct

```
struct Foo
{
   std::vector<int> X;
}
```

In the above case delete f will free the vector as well.

```
Foo* f = new Foo();
delete f;
```

If your **Foo** is defined like so.. you need to provide a destructor.

```
struct Foo
{
   std::vector<int> *X;
   Foo()
   { 
       X = new std::vector<int> ();
   }

   ~Foo()
   {
      delete X;
   }
}
```

You can pick from either of the two approaches. The best approach is to use a **[shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)** so that you don't have to worry about deleteing the struct even

Answer (score 0):

You might be overthinking things. When you destroy *any* object, all member objects are automatically destroyed.

```
struct Foo
{
  Bar x;
  std::vector<int> y;
};

int main()
{
  Foo a;
  Foo * p(new Foo);
  delete p; // #2
} // #1
```

At point #1, `a` goes out of scope, so it is destroyed. This involves destroying `a.y` and `a.x` (in this order), and the same for the destruction of `*p` and `p->x`/`p->y` in #2. Whether the `Foo` object was allocated automatically (as in #1) or dynamically (as in #2) is immaterial; all members get cleaned up properly.